# jquery or JS create child element and assign an ID

Tags: javascript, html, json

I've been working through this and I'm a little stuck. I can't seem to find a direct answer so  I'm gonna ask.

I'm creating an options list from a JSON call. I've created the child elements but I can't seem to add the unique ID's (stored in the JSON) to each element. When I create the ID inside the $.each of the JSON I get the last ID from the call assigned to all the options.

Thanks

```
$("#fDistList").append('<option>' + item.GROUP_NAME + '</option>');
$("option").attr('id', item.ID);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
$("#fDistList").append('<option id="'+ item.ID + '">' + item.GROUP_NAME + '</option>');
```

When you do

```
$("option").attr('id', item.ID);
```

you are reselecting all `option` elements and setting their ID attribute.

Comment: thanks, that was it...the double quotes inside the single quotes I wasn't even considering that to be an option but it makes so much sense now.

Answer (score 4):

You could do it like this, in a single pass

```
$('<option/>',{
        text: item.GROUP_NAME, 
        id:item.ID
    }).appendTo('#fDistList');
```

Comment: Do you have a link for the documentation for this? I need to learn more about this single pass, its much cleaner.

Comment: @atlMapper, see the 2nd version of http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery2 for creating elements with a map of properties, and http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/ for appending to elements